# Keep state in child component when state in parent component changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React collapsible table where the rows contain buttons that enable to edit the data of products fetched from database. However, when these buttons are clicked, the rows close because the state is altered in the parent component which leads to the state being reset in the child component. The default state for "openRow" is false.

I have a function in Row which alters the state of 'products' in Products. This causes the openRow in all rows to be reset to false, even though I would like to keep the opened rows open. How can I keep them open when the state of products changes?

```
export default function Products() {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    function Row({product}) {
        const [openRow, setOpenRow] = useState(false);

    }

}
```

Comment: It will be great, If you can share your code, so we can get to know about the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you declared one component inside another. **You should never do this.**

```
export default function Products() {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

}

function Row({product}) {
    const [openRow, setOpenRow] = useState(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me solve the issue. By having these components separate and passing down the functions from Products I needed to call in Row as props made this go smoothly and as wanted.